# Expired ack deadline while message is acknowledged well within time

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

On one subscription, I'm seeing occasional redelivery of messages. This seems to happen due to an expired ack deadline, which I can tell by looking at the "expired ack deadlines count" metric.

The subscription is configured with an ack deadline of 360 seconds. The vast majority of the messages are acked within one second, and some messages take 20-30 seconds. Sometimes one of these "slow" messages result in an expired ack deadline, but most don't.

I'm using the Java client, and have configured a "max outstanding element count" of 10. This means that at most 10 messages are pulled from PubSub, which are then processed. Even if all 10 messages would take 30 seconds, the last message (they're processed in sequence) should still be acked within 360 seconds. However this scenario never happens: the rate of messages is not very high, and only very few messages take more than 1 second. At the times of the expired ack deadlines, there was always only one slow (20-30 sec) message being processed.

Furthermore, when I look at the "Ack latency" metric, it matches my expections: mostly < 1 sec, with occasional peeks to max 30 seconds. It never gets even close to the ack deadline of 360 seconds.

Can anyone think of a reason why some messages are suffering from an expired ack deadline? Are there maybe other metrics or settings that I can verify? Or is my understanding of ack deadlines maybe incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the ack deadline expires due to slow processing in the subscriber. This slow processing could take on many forms. It could be that the user callback is taking too long to process and acknowledge the message. Based on your investigation, it does not sound like this is what is happening.

Another possibility is if you have the client set to use [multiple streams](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/concurrency-control#concurrency_control_configurations). If you set the "max outstanding element count" to 10, then each stream will allow up to 10 messages to be outstanding. However, in this case, the client library will only allow up to 10 messages to be outstanding to your callback, which means the remaining messages may be held in the client library until you ack some outstanding messages. Typically, these messages would not expire unless you have set the [max ack extension](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management#lease_management_configuration) to something relatively low. In such a case, you may want to set parallel pull count (or the equivalent in whatever language you are using) to 1.

Finally, the ack deadline for a message could expire if there is a transient server-side or network issue that prevents the message from being delivered to your client in a timely fashion. In such a case, it could be that the message was sent from the server, but could not be delivered in time and therefore the ack deadline expired. Such issues are going to happen, albeit they should be relatively rare assuming a good network connection between your client and Google Cloud.

Comment: I'm using the Java client with default settings for parallel pull count, which seems to be 1. If I understand you correctly, this can't be the problem then.
Network issues seem unlikely, too, because I am receiving other messages at these times. We're also using other Google Cloud services, and not experiencing network issues there.

Comment: Depending on the frequency, it could be network connections to individual servers given that systems like Pub/Sub are massively distributed. For any more follow-up, you'd need to put in a support ticket.